# std::sort invocation causes subscript out of range compile-time error

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

The below code fails to compile with error: "array subscript 16 is outside array bounds of …".
I don't understand why, `w` is guaranteed to be <= arr1.size().

https://godbolt.org/z/5n5KohsnW

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

extern bool test_func();

int tempfunc() 
{
    std::array<std::tuple<double,int>,5> arr1;
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        if( test_func()) {
            arr1[w] = {3.,4};
            w++;
        }
    }
    std::sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.begin() + w);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `w` after the `for` loop has terminated?

Comment: @TimRandall 5 or less, as stated in the question. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: At a glance, this seems to be a regression introduced in gcc 12.  The runtime value of `w` should not trigger an error at compile time.

Comment: Judging by the stack, it looks like it's trying to execute the `std::sort` as `constexpr`, despite not knowing what `w` is, which means it thinks there's undefined behavior somewhere, and therefore has assumed `w` is some specific constant.

Comment: Aha, if `test_func` ever returned false, then some elements of `arr1` would be uninitialized for the sort. Since that's undefined behavior, the compiler assumes that can't happen, and therefore that `test_func` only returns true, which means `w` is 6.... but how did it get to index 16?

Comment: @MooingDuck *`w` is 6* How do 5 loop iterations and 5 `w++` make it 6? *that's undefined behavior* OP uses `arr1.begin() + w`, there is no UB there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Another gcc optimization frankenbug. Join the party... Bug 100366, bug 108165, what's one more?

Comment: There's "nothing" wrong with sorting over a range that may contain uninitialized values.

Comment: @sweenish I don't see how it can be uninitialised, an element is initialised every time `w` is incremented

Comment: @AlanBirtles You're right. Never mind me.

Comment: using `size_t` as an index along with adding a `std::min` fixes it but its definitely a compiler bug: https://godbolt.org/z/q4h5KjK7s

Comment: Adding the "missing" test_func results in [no compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/qornqjT1e).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that completely changes the optimisation, the compiler now knows exactly what the function is going to do so can completely work out the result of the function at compile time

Comment: Which range do you think contains uninitialized values @sweenish? `w` is initialized to 0, and gets incremented only when a value gets added to `arr1`; as such the range passed to `std::sort` is fully initialized.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Your comment is late and unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It will still error out if the function can return either/or. https://godbolt.org/z/eqa75MEYG

Comment: Well, I do tend to be a bit slow, @sweenish; I like to take the time to review everything, and make sure I get things right. I must admit that it makes me a bit tardy, sometimes. Instead of "measure twice, cut once", my motto is "think twice, say or write once". It worked out well for me, in the past.

Comment: Even simpler code reproduces issue: https://godbolt.org/z/zW1Wjfcbh if only compiler is unable to determine `w` value it raises this `array-bounds` warning. So just report a bug to gcc and provide link here.

Comment: As a workaround you can disable this specific warning: `-Werror=array-bounds=0`: https://godbolt.org/z/WEjMxaP7E

Comment: Thanks all. Seems like the consensus is that it's an issue with gcc. I don't have access to gcc bugzilla. Hopefully a kind soul reading this can report for us.

Comment: This warning has quite long (185) list of open bugs: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=array-bounds

Comment: Alternate workaround: Change your declaration to `std::vector<std::tuple<double,int>> arr1(5);
`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It didn't exactly work out for you this time, though. You were just slow. I own my mistakes. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I own my mistakes too, @sweenish. The thing is, though, they're extremely rare. Hence it might take a little while before I get an opportunity to prove that to you.

Comment: Saying that something "fails to compile" when you pass -Werror is misleading, you should just say that it emits a (bogus) warning.

Answer (score -1):

The error can be caused by different behavior on various compilers. Also related to the w variable because the function bool test_func(); can return false as the if condition inside your loop which means w isn't guaranteed the value of 5 each time we're done (can be less depending on function return).

You can solve it by changing w to 5 in your sort line or even better arr1.size() would do as well since it's going to be size 5 as initially declared.

```
std::sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.begin() + 5);
```

Or replace it with this instead:

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1));
```

Also, to print value of each tuple, try this inside your loop:

```
std::cout << "First is: " << std::get<0>(arr1[i]) << " and Second is " << std::get<1>(arr1[i]) << std::endl;
```

Comment: How it returning false explains the error?

Comment: I edited my answer. Check again. It's related to variable w. I've tested this in my compiler as well as the given online compiler link.

Comment: I don't see how this change is related to OP's error. Their code should work as is.

Comment: The offset given to the sort function for the array of tuples is over the actual size of the array. It is trying to sort array elements for something of size other than the array actually holds (5 elements).

Comment: `w` can never be bigger than `5` in OP's code.

Comment: Why is it not good? What's wrong with wanting to sort only first `w` elements, as long as `w <= 5`?

Comment: Sorting w elements as long as w <= 5 is fine. There's more to it here.
Behavior can vary on different compilers that's why the suggested fixes to sort statement fixes this across different compilers.

Comment: Why would it vary across compilers? This looks like just a buggy warning, nothing more.

Comment: Well, since OP's online compiler uses latest gcc 13.1, I can see that it gives a warning about sort insertion and it's trying to access array subscript 16 which is outside our range of 5 or less. My suggestions resolve this. If it's a bug or undefined behavior for gcc then that's something they need to fix.

std::sort performs an insertion if I understand correctly?

Comment: Your fix changes the behavior. They're trying to sort first `w` elements, not all of them. *"undefined behavior for gcc"* UB is something the standard defines. It doesn't depend on a compiler. *"std::sort performs an insertion"* What do you mean?

Comment: Then perhaps use a different online compiler and keep the same code for now until gcc 13.1 bug is resolved.

There are:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler
https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_compiler.asp
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: It seems similar to the difference between string.at(index) vs string[index].
The bracket operator performs an insertion first.
Same for accessing map elements.


at() does bounds checking, exception of type std::out_of_range will be thrown on invalid access.

operator[] does NOT check bounds and thus can be dangerous if you try to access beyond the bounds of the string. It is a little faster than at though.

Answer (score -1):

A suggestion would be to use something like a map (unordered map and sort it at the end or simply ordered map) over an array of tuples where the key/value pairs are <double, int> if issue persists with latest GCC.